# Testing JavaScript callback functions with jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jspec

I have the following functions:

```
function getPersonData(id) {
  retrieveData(
    id,
    function(person) {
      if(person.name) {
        displayPerson(person);
      }
    }
}

function retrieveData(id, successCallBack) {
    executeRequest(id, {
      success: successCallBack
    });
}
```

`getPersonData` retrieves a person's information based on the id. It in turn calls `retrieveData` by passing in the id and a successCallBack function.

`retrieveData` takes the id and successCallBack and calls another function, `executeRequest`, which gets the data and passes back a person object.

I am trying to test `getPersonData` and have the following spec set up

```
describe("when getPersonData is called with the right person id", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(projA.data, "retrieveData").and.returnValue(
      {
        'name': 'john'
      }
    );
    spyOn(projA.data, "displayPerson");
    projA.data.getPersonData("123");
  });

  it("displays the person's details", function() {
    expect(projA.data.displayPerson).toHaveBeenCalled();
  );
});
```

But when the spec is executed the `displayPerson` method isn't called. This is because the person data being passed back from the success callBack `function(person)` isn't being passed in even though I have mocked `retrieveData` to return a result.

My question is:
Is this the right way to test callBack functions? Either way what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess using `returnValue` for a function that doesn't return a value wouldn't work. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I have decided to move `function(person) {
      if(person.name) {
        displayPerson(person);
      }
    }` to a new method to help with testing. But I would still like to know how the above code could be tested.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so jasmine is tricky in a lot of subtle ways and I think there's two main issues with your code

1. You have way too many asynchronous calls wrapped in each other. Which is by itself not a problem, but it makes testing in JASMINE hell of a lot harder. For example, what is the point of having a `retrieveData` function which just calls `executeRequest` function with the exact same parameters but in a slightly different way.

I rewrote your getPersonData to be like this

```
function getPersonData(id) {
  // this is needed to properly spy in Jasmine
  var self = this;

  //replaced retrieveData with just execute request
  // self is required to properly spy in Jasmine
  self.executeRequest(id, {
    success: function(person) {
     if (person.name) {
      self.displayPerson(person);
     }
    }
  })
}

//I don't know what exactly executeRequest does 
//but I took the liberty to just make it up for this example 
function executeRequest(id, callback) {
 callback.success({
   name: id
  });
}

//I also assumed that projA would look something like this
var projA = {
 data: {
  getPersonData: getPersonData,
  retrieveData: retrieveData,
  displayPerson: displayPerson,
  executeRequest: executeRequest
 }
};
```

2. In order to test asynchronous code in Jasmine, you need to include a `done` callback with the test. Also, if you expect a callback function to fire automatically, you need to set it up within a `setTimeout` function, otherwise it will never fire. Here's an adjusted example:

```
    describe("when getPersonData is called with the right person id",  function() {
     beforeEach(function() {
      //you should not spyOn retriveData or executeCode because it will override the function you wrote and will never call displayPerson

      // you should only have spies on the methods you are testing otherwise they will override other methods
      spyOn(projA.data, "displayPerson");
     });

     it("displays the person's details", function(done) {
      // it's better to call the function within specific test blocks so you have control over the test
      projA.data.getPersonData("123");

      // at this point, it will just have called the getPersonData but will not call executeRequest
      setTimeout(function() {
       //this block will just call executeRequest
       setTimeout(function() {
        //this block will finally call displayPerson
        expect(projA.data.displayPerson).toHaveBeenCalled();

        //tell jasmine the test is done after this
        done();
        })
       })
     });
    })
```